# Add ubuntu forums link to opinion close reason?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

I was on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779980/better-to-suspend-my-ubuntu-or-shut-down-it-during-long-journey-in-car?noredirect=1#comment1167403_779980) and was discussing closing the question as opinion based with @ipselute and the idea came up that it would me a good idea to send this question to Ubuntu forums where it could be discussed.

Do you think we should have the close reason direct users to the Ubuntu forums where there issues can be discussed?

It seems to me, it would be a lot better for these users than getting a few opinions here.

Comment: Disagree because there are many cases where a question is just so opinion based its not valid on the forums either...

Comment: I was under the impression that the forums would allow discussion of anything as long as it was Ubuntu related, I must admit though I haven't actually spent that much time there.

Comment: There are wildly offtopic sections of the forum yes but "Ubuntu or Debian?" is so wildly opinion based its a "why are you asking this on an Ubuntu area"

Answer (score 5):

Directing users to the Ubuntu forums to solicit opinions sounds logical to me. It then makes the scopes of Ask Ubuntu, Ubuntu forums and the Ubuntu subreddit very clear: Ask Ubuntu for clear-cut questions and answers, Ubuntu forums for opinions and long discussions, and the Ubuntu subreddit for anything not related to technical support.

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with the close reasons on this question.

> This is not really a technical support issue and will be closed, it is really up to you and your needs, all anyone can offer is opinion.

We don't just do technical support here, we answer all sorts of non-technical questions.

I don't understand how this question is unanswerable. You're given two options, suspend or shutdown, one keeps track of state at the risk of data loss, the other does not keep track of state but your data is safer. That's pretty much what an accepted answer would look like.

Comment: It is not that the question is "unanswerable", it is that people can only give there opinion on it. The question does not ask "what is the difference between suspend and shutdown", that would be a perfectly valid question, it says "shall I suspend Ubuntu, or shut it down, for data and laptop safety during the long car drive?" Well, how long is this journey? How long will the Laptop last on suspend? We don't know any details about it and can only offer our subjective, opinion / experience, I really think a discussion back and forth on Ubuntu forums would benefit the OP a lot more.